# Blazor multiple keys handling bug

Tags: c#, blazor

To control an object and camera I built a blazor page which handles key events to do so.
The keys "W", "A", "S", "D" control movement while the cursor keys control the camera fixed to the object. 
To handle all usual cases I have to bind to the keydown and keyup events. However this doesn't work as expected.

When pressing "W" (and holding it down) then pressing "S" (and holding it down as well), then releasing "W", onkeyup is fired but reporting the wrong key "S".
The same procedure works like a charm for the cursor keys.

The issue is very easy to reproduce:

`<input type="text" @onkeyup="HandleKeyUp" />`

```
@code
{
    private void HandleKeyUp(KeyboardEventArgs evArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Keyup:" + evArgs.Key.ToLower());
    }
}
```

I'm using .NET Core 3.0 server side blazor and Microsoft Edge to show the page. I realized that when using Firefox the keys are reported as expected. On the other hand, Edge correctly reports the key-ups when using JavaScript. So I suppose this is a Blazor bug.

I'd like to know if this is a known bug (I couldn't find anything about it) or how I could work around this issue other than changing the webbrowser.

**Edit:**
I tried upgrading the project to .NET Core 3.1: Same issue. I created a brand new project with .NET Core 3.1: Same issue.
Here's a temporary link to the simplified repro: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkDtbKuES9_qjcZHghNBCc93jp4NBA?e=QiQXDh
It's basically a stripped down new standard blazor project.
Edge version is 44.18362.449.0.

Comment: I tested your code exactly on Chrome 79,Firefox 71.0 and Edge  44.18362.449.0 and am not able to reproduce your issue. I am using .Net CORE 3.1.

What version of firefox and .net core are you using? If you are using .core 3.0, maybe try upgrading to 3.1

Comment: And to make sure I'm understanding your issue, I am holding down D, then pressing and releasing E, and on all three browsers my evArgs.Key is E and not D as expected.

Comment: After rereading your question, I have also tried holding down D, then holding down E, and while both are still held down, releasing the first key (D), and I am correctly getting D reported with all three browsers as well.

If you are on the same updated version of browsers and using .net core 3.1, Can you try making a full minimal reproducible  example to post? May also be worth opening a github ticket.

Comment: @Kyle: Thank you for the tests! I stated I'm on .NET Core 3.0. But luckily I'm not fixed to this version. I'm going to give it a try with 3.1 tomorrow.

Comment: Opps, sorry I missed that apparently. I'm guessing it was fixed in 3.1 then, but let me know if it's not - pretty curious.

Comment: Did 3.1 fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Please note my additions from the weekend. If you‘d try out the repro it might help to find out the reasons, thank you!

Comment: I'll give it a try tonight if I can. Unfortunately my workplace network restrictions block url shorteners for some reason..

Comment: @Kyle: Have you been able to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems related to an Edge Browser bug. Even when trying with simple JavaScript handling e.g. on this site https://javascript.info/keyboard-events the issue can be reproduced (other than I reported previously). As already stated, other browsers work fine.

There are various other threads back from 2017 reporting keyboard handling issues with Edge.

**EDIT: With Edge 79.0.309.71 the issue is gone.**